# sorting multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am new to dataframes, and I wanted to know how could I sort a list of 3 dataframes, where each dataframe has a size of n x n. For example like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[11,12,13]], columns = ['a,','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[6,1,9],[0,3,2],[12,14,10]], columns = ['a,','b','c'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,8],[2,1,1],[10,16,15]], columns = ['a,','b','c'])
j = [df1,df2,df3]
```

and I wanted to sort j by the number in the first row and second column of each dataframe in descending order. So j = [df1,df2,df3] becomes j = [df3,df1,df2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sorted`, giving it a key function to pull out the entry in the first row, second column:

```
sorted(j, key=lambda x: x.iloc[0,1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for like an entire day.